# How to retrieve a whole mailbox with Spring Integration Mail

Tags: email, spring-integration

I'm trying to create a piece of code that would retrieve the whole content of an INBOX, using Spring Integration Mail.
By default, an ImapIdleChannelAdapter will only fetch recent, unseen, unanswered etc... emails.
So when I created my adapter, I tried to use a special strategy that would retrieve all emails without a given unique user flag (so basically, all the mails I haven't retrieve yet).

Here is my adapter:

```
Mail.imapIdleAdapter(imapUrl(user, pw, provider))
            .javaMailProperties { p: PropertiesBuilder -> p.put("mail.debug", "false") }
            .userFlag(uniqueFlag)
            .shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(false)
            .searchTermStrategy(GetAllMailsStrategy(uniqueFlag))
            .shouldReconnectAutomatically(true)
            .autoCloseFolder(false)

val integrationFlowBuilder = IntegrationFlows.from(imapIdleAdapter)
            .handle { message -> onNewEmail(user, uniqueFlag, message as org.springframework.messaging.Message<Message>) }

        val flow: IntegrationFlow = integrationFlowBuilder.get()

        flowContext.registration(flow).register()
```

And here is my strategy:

```
inner class GetAllMailsStrategy(private val uniqueFlag: String) : SearchTermStrategy {
        override fun generateSearchTerm(supportedFlags: Flags?, folder: Folder?): SearchTerm {
            val userFlag = Flags()
            userFlag.add(uniqueFlag)
            return NotTerm(FlagTerm(userFlag, true))
        }
    }
```

This piece of code does work, on small inboxes. As soon as I try to retrieve mails from an inbox with thousands of mails, at some point it just stops (sometime with FolderClosedException, even though I set autoCloseFolder to false, and sometime without any exception or log...), and then won't retrieve missing emails even if I start it all over with the same unique user flag. As if all the mails where flagged even though I never retrieved them. It does work on all new incoming emails though...

Any idea on what strategy I should use? Is there a way to get all the mails once, without flagging them?
Should I use Spring mail only to get incoming new mail but something else for the task of retrieving all the mails once?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I never did it, but I think you are right: you should use an `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` for new (in IMAP terms `RECENT`) message, and some other `ImapMailReceiver` instance for initial call with your custom `SearchTermStrategy`.

The folder might be closed for some other reason, e.g. too many messages too long processed.